# Checking for Integers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a regular expression where I'm checking if a text entry is numeric. This is Year field and it should accept only integers like 1999 or 2000 etc. But in this case it's also accepting -, +, . etc.

```
isNumeric = function(b){
    return(b-0) == b&&(b+"").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").length > 0
};
```

Could you please help me out!!

Comment: `return /\d{4}/.test(b)`

Comment: @pawel Why isNumeric("+1234") is true??

Comment: because it passes the above test, sorry ;) use `/^\d{4}$/.test(b)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to accept years of 20<sup>th</sup> and 21<sup>th</sup> centuries, a more refined regexp could be

```
isNumeric = function(b){
    return /^(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(b)
};
```

if you need to accept always a 4-digit year, the regular expression is simply

```
/^\d{4}$/
```

and if you need to accept every year from 0 to 9999 (where a trailing 0 is not accepted)

```
/^(0|[1-9]\d{0,3})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check it like:

```
if(!isNaN(parseInt(yourstring))){

}
```

and using regex you can do:

```
/^[0-9]+$/i.test(yourstring)
```

Comment: `parseInt("+123") == 123`

Answer (score 1):

better solution is to restrict user to enter key other than Numeric using Javascript Create function like this:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and add `onkeypress` Event to your Textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7"
onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

Demo: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/)

You can also restrict user to enter only 4 Numerics by adding  `maxlength="4"` to inbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to validate a range of (positive) years for example 1980 to 2020 where the string '+2000' is not accepted.

```
isNumeric = function(b){
    return /^(198\d|200\d|2020)$/.test(b);
}
```

This will pass the following tests - it's tested [here](http://www.unittest.it/unittestcase/DllC87Q/)

Function renamed to yearRange

```
yearRange = function(b){
    return /^(198\d|200\d|2020)$/.test(b);
}


test('Year range validation', function() {
   equal( yearRange(1979), false, '1979 returns false');
   equal( yearRange(1980), true, '1980 returns true');
   equal( yearRange('2000'), true, 'The string 2000 returns true');
   equal( yearRange(+2000), true, '+2000 returns true' );
   equal( yearRange(-2000), false, '-2000 returns false' );
   equal( yearRange('+2000'), false, 'The string +2000 returns false');
   equal( yearRange('-2000'), false, 'The string -2000 returns false');
});
```